# nuclide server starts but feature not implemented

Tags: node.js, nuclide-editor

I'm trying to connect remote workspace on nulcide 
adn here is my setup

Server Ubuntu 14.04
node -v
v7.2.1
npm -v
3.10.10
watchman -v
4.7.0

Client Mac
node -v
v7.2.1
npm -v
3.10.9
watchman -v
4.7.0

When I try connecting server, I get following message
"Unable to connect to server"
The server successfully started, but we were unable to connect.
Original error message:
 Not implemented

How to solve this?

Comment: I suggest adding more information to this question. It doesn't show things you have tried to fix the issue.

Comment: I made sure that versions are similar and followed steps on nuclide.io/docs/features/remote/#nuclide-server__prerequisites but doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open ports for `nuclide` as 9090?